# Create a continuous date string in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I create a continious date string like this in matlab:

```
'20160801'
'20160802'
'20160803'
.
.
.
'20161031'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
% Define the starting and ending dates from literal representations...
date_start = datetime('20160801','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
date_end = datetime('20161031','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');

% Create a range of dates using the colon operator...
date_range = (date_start:date_end).';

% Convert the dates back to the desired literal format...
date_text = datestr(date_range,'yyyyMMdd');
```